# access object of Qlist<object> member of QAbstractListModel inside QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

We have `QAbstractlistModel` derived class ( lets name it **A** )

and a `QObject` derived class (lets name this **B**)

class `A` has a member:  `QList(B) modelList`

`modelList` is accessible in QML using `Q_PROPERTY` macro

class `B` has a member: `QList(QVariant) data`

also `data` is accesable in QML using `Q_PROPERTY` macro

`data` items are user defined `structs` (which also are known to qml through `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`)

`A` and `B` are registered in main using `qmlRegisterType`

class `B` and all of its structures are accessible in QML when we create new object of that

but if  I want to access `B` object's property inside `modelList`, just recive *undefined*

and if  print `modelList` items ,it shows : `QVariant(B,) QVariant(B,) QVariant(B,) QVariant(B,) ...`

(as `QAbstractListModel::data` return type is `QVariant` , I convert class `B` to `QVariant` to be able to return it )

**Q:** am I in right way ? Is there any way to cast `QVariant(B,)` to `B` in QML, to access `data` inside it?

Comment: please provide [mcve], there is no need to explain your code.

Comment: > *but if I want to access B object's property inside modelList, just recive undefined* Of course, you have to do the actual acessing in c++ and then expose a wrapper method to QML. Everything you want to access in QML needs to be explicitly exposed in C++ code

Comment: since it is a QAbstractListModel, you can make it multi-level, giving a rowCount for the specific cell according to the size of your QObjectList